# How to set WebView font

Tags: android, html, webview

I'm trying to set the html of my `WebView` to as;

```
    "<html>" +
        "<head>" +
            "<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html;\" charset=\"UTF-8\">" +
            "<style type=\"text/css\">" +
                "@font-face {" +
                        "font-family: 'SourceSansPro Regular'; " +
                        "src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf' +
                        // "/android_asset/fonts
                        "/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf');" +
                    "} " +
                "body {" +
                    "font-family: 'SourceSansPro Regular';" +
                    // "color:f00;" +
                "}" +
            "</style> " +
        "</head> " +
        "<body>" +
            " My Html Data"+
        "</body>" +
    "</html>";
```

But font is not being applied. The font applied well if I create an html file in assets folder. But I need to set body dynamically so can't use this way.

Comment: where is  SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf in your project?

Comment: it should be under assets/font (assets is NOT in res)

Answer (score 3):

Using webview websettings you can set your default font family for webview

```
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setStandardFontFamily("Roboto-Light");
```

//if it is a system font else parse the font family from asset or from style as follows,

```
int[] attrs = { android.R.attr.fontFamily };
        TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.myFontStyle, attrs);
        String fontfamily = a.getString(0);

        // Main
        webSettings.setStandardFontFamily(fontfamily);
```

**Note** :
Even if you use this API : setStandardFontFamily to specify the font family webview will give the priority to font which is coming from server(html page)

**eg:**

1. if html page not specified any font then it will take this dynamic
   font family.

   2.html specified font is not available then it will take our dynamic font in webview

Other than this Priority is given for serverpage font family not a dynamic.

Comment: How to apply custom font with this API?

Comment: In this example it is given, but it is like instead of doing in direct html file , it parses the html file and done dynamically http://bho.googlecode.com/git-history/ebe5bb8609cb1937593b25567df6cd77ebda4287/BhoView/src/org/ironrabbit/SharCheBrowserActivity.java  So far i didn't found .any straightforward approach like webview.setfont..(fromasst). Since you want to use the font dynamically then you can push your font into the system/font  and specify in fw font/font.xml(from L onwards) and use it directly like roboto font family - tedious but flexible.

Comment: What is myFontStyle?

Comment: I was not able to get this working, can you please explain it further?